# JPG image not showing on secure page in IE8

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer

Can someone kindly tell me why the JPG at the bottom isn't appearing in IE8?

http://order.organiclifeonline.com/ravinia-school

I've tried doing some research, but can't find a concise answer.  Does it have to do with the page being https?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is served from a non-HTTPS URL which is why IE8 by default ignores to show it. The default behavior is also affected by your browser security settings too.

Answer (score 0):

Load it in via https, not http, thats probably the issue

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because of a browser security policy around HTTPS.  In some configurations, IE won't display insecure content on an HTTPS page.

Here are the warnings on your page:

```
The page at https://order.organiclifeonline.com/ravinia-school displayed insecure content from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:regular,bold&v1.
The page at https://order.organiclifeonline.com/ravinia-school displayed insecure content from http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v1/EFpQQyG9GqCrobXxL-KRMcBaWKZ57bY3RXgXH6dOjZ0.ttf.
The page at https://order.organiclifeonline.com/ravinia-school displayed insecure content from http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v1/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciMDdSZkkecOE1hvV7ZHvhyU.ttf.
The page at https://order.organiclifeonline.com/ravinia-school displayed insecure content from http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v1/EFpQQyG9GqCrobXxL-KRMcBaWKZ57bY3RXgXH6dOjZ0.ttf.
The page at https://order.organiclifeonline.com/ravinia-school displayed insecure content from http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v1/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciMDdSZkkecOE1hvV7ZHvhyU.ttf.
The page at https://order.organiclifeonline.com/ravinia-school displayed insecure content from http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v1/EFpQQyG9GqCrobXxL-KRMcBaWKZ57bY3RXgXH6dOjZ0.ttf.
The page at https://order.organiclifeonline.com/ravinia-school displayed insecure content from http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/droidsans/v1/s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciMDdSZkkecOE1hvV7ZHvhyU.ttf.
The page at https://order.organiclifeonline.com/ravinia-school displayed insecure content from http://www.organiclifeonline.com/school-menus/3.jpg.
```